# Вылетает программа при выполнении int21 9

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания

Использую masm32, запутался во всех примерах, где то fasm,tasm разные модели, указатели... В примерах нужно было использовать 16-битные регистры, но так компилятор вызывал ошибку о несовместимости размеров регистра и указателя строки.
И что использовать для обозначения конца строки в masm? Где то пишут 0, где то $.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

data segment 
    stroka db "10",0,"$"
data ends

text segment
start:
    mov edx, offset stroka
    mov eax, 09h
    int 21h


    ret
text ends
end start
```

Comment: Уж на крайняк, посоветуйте книгу(на русском, masm, с примерами, и самую хорошую на ваш взгляд)

Comment: Как компилируете? Я подозреваю, что вы компилируете в исполняемый файл для Windows, а под Windows использовать прерывания нельзя. В этом случае вам нужно найти уроки именно по программированию на Ассемблере под Windows.

Comment: Как это под windows использовать прерывания нельзя(-_-). А как же тогда делать все фишки, которые дают прерывания? Я так понял нужно под dos компилировать? будет ли в таком случае работать на 64 битной системе? И если нет прерываний, то вместо них есть альтернатива, или только WinApi остается?

Comment: Да, компилируете dos (можно из Windows, но получить нужно исполняемый файл для dos). На 64-битной системе работать не будет. Под windows - WinAPI. Какие именно "фишки" прерываний вам нужны?

Comment: вызов другого приложения, работа с файловой таблицей, считывание с клавиатуры нажатий и вывод в консоль. Для этого вроде есть аналоги в WinApi, но в таком варианте лучше использовать C,С++.  Сильно изменится размер программы, если пару проц команд заменить на функции из WinApi?

Comment: По поводу файловой таблицы не могу сказать, но есть утилиты, которые с ней работают из самой Windows, значит это можно делать через WinAPI. Размер программы при переходе из dos на windows в любом случае изменится - как минимум потому что заголовок исполняемого файла другой, а размер секций по-умолчанию выравнивается под 1 Кб, если мне не изменяет память, так что просто скомпилированный экзешник у вас будет где-то 4 килобайта.

Comment: *"под Windows использовать прерывания нельзя"* -- однозначно в анналы! А мужики-то не знают...

Comment: @PinkTux, я решил, что не стоит перегружать новичка излишними в данный момент знаниями типа int3 и нулевого кольца. Плюс в контексте вопроса комментарий был по прерываниям dos/bios.

Comment: Сказал "А", говори "Б")), если знаете книгу которая обхватывает и этот вопрос дайте плз.

Comment: @SergG, если вы не собираетесь писать драйвера, то считайте, что прерывания под Windows вам недоступны. Для начала я бы посоветовал какую-нибудь из книг А.Крупника по ассемблеру. Сам начинал учиться давно и по чем попало, Крупника только пролистывал, но могу сказать что все доступно объясняется.

Comment: @SergG, "Ralf Brown's Interrupt List". Если это действительно надо...